# python indention error

Tags: python, google-docs

New to python, been writing this about an hour. Google docs api and examples are great. I can connect and create files, etc. I want to backup all my files to a google drive, so tried using `os.walk` and ran into a persistent indentation error I don't understand.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2
import pprint
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.client import Credentials
import os
import sys

rootdir = sys.argv[1]

CLIENT_ID = 'MYCLIENT ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'MY SECRET ID'
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

# Redirect URI for installed apps
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

json_creds = open('backup_credentials.json', 'r').read()
credentials = Credentials.new_from_json(json_creds)
#
# Create an httplib2.Http object and authorize it with our credentials
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

#Here is where the problem starts
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for filename in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
        print (filepath)
        media_body = MediaFileUpload(filepath, mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
        body = {'title': filename,'description': 'A test document','mimeType': 'text/plain'}
        file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
        pprint.pprint(file)
```

The offending error is the line file = ...

Actual error is

```
File "./quickstart.py", line 59
  file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
                                                                              ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: Your indentation is off after `body = {`

Comment: Don't mix tabs and spaces.  [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) says "Never mix tabs and spaces.

The most popular way of indenting Python is with spaces only. The second-most popular way is with tabs only. Code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces exclusively. **When invoking the Python command line interpreter with the -t option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs and spaces.** When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options are highly recommended!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have

```
    body = {
     'title': filename,
     'description': 'A test document',
     'mimeType': 'text/plain'
  }  
  file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
  pprint.pprint(file)
```

when you should have:

```
    body = {
     'title': filename,
     'description': 'A test document',
     'mimeType': 'text/plain'
    }
    file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
    pprint.pprint(file)
```

Notice that the `file =` line should be indented to the same level that the line "above" it is indented (`body = ...`).

Comment: Thanks. Actually trying to paste the code into stackoverflow screwed up the original indention. If there is an easy way to paste python code that would be great. I had it intended that way, but it still didn't work. So I just ended up combining all the contents of body ={} into one line and now I'm ok. In python if you are going to do multiple lines like in body, do you have to escape it or do something special or it will screw up your idention?

Comment: @glacierDiscomfort -- breaking it up into multiple lines like that should be fine.  In python, any unterminated braces, brackets and parenthesis are automatically converted into a single line.

Comment: [Implicit line joining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining) explains what mgilson mentioned in detail.

Comment: many thanks to all for the helpful feedback!